# Find coordinates in 3rd quadrant given distance of $0.08$ from origin where $x$ and $y$ are the same value

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> "What are the coordinates of the point which has a distance of 0.08m away from the origin. the x and y are both equal to each other and are also negative values?"

I've tried using the distance formula $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$ and the closest number I got was like $0.05656$ for both $x$ and $y$ but I'm not entirely sure how to do it without just putting random numbers into the calculator as trial and error, is there a certain method that I can use to do this or is it just complete trial and error?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there!

The point you are looking for is one of the intersections between the circle
$x^2+y^2=0.8^2$ and the line $y=x$.

Substitute and get

$2x^2=0.0064\to x^2= 0.0032\to x=\pm \sqrt{0.0032}\to x\approx\pm 0.0565685$

The point you need is $(-0.0565685,-0.0565685)$